# Group By with max count and max date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a warehouse with thousand of stock unit with a unique code, the Item Code, the Quantity and the Generation Date (Date the stock unit was "born").

My manager asked me to extract for every Item (starts with char '2') the maximum stock unit count with the same quantity and the quantity.

I wrote this query and i think it worked:

```
with a as 
(
select c.*
from (
        Select Item, Qty, count (Qty) as cnt
        from SI_UDC
        GROUP BY Item, Qty
        ) as c
    inner join 
    (     
        Select item, max(cnt) as maxtotal
        from  (
                Select item, Qty, count (Qty) as cnt
                from SI_UDC
                GROUP BY item, Qty 
                ) as u 
                group by Item
                ) as t
    on c.item = t.item and c.cnt = t.maxtotal
where LEFT(c.item,1)='2' 
)
```

I have a situation like this:

```
Item - Qty - cnt

270526 - 900 - 1

280102 - 25600 - 27
```

It seems it works.

When I checked the data I saw for some Item i have the same count number with  different quantity:

```
Item - Qty - cnt

270432 - 600 - 5

270432 - 920 - 5
```

I asked my manager which data i have to extract and it reply the quantity of the group with the most recent stock unit.

Panic.

I've been trying for days but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?
First question: Is it the best query I can write? or is there a better way?
Second and most important question: How can i extract the group with most recent stock unit if i have multiple group for an Item?

I Hope I explained the situation as well as possible

Thanks in advance

Here how the table SI_UDC looks like:

```
ID          item   qty    GenerationDate
PL1007546   240357 120000 2017-09-20 22:00:00.000
PL1007547   240357 2304   2016-04-10 18:00:00.000
PL1007548   240359 1980   2017-08-01 10:00:00.000
PL1007549   240354 620    2015-02-05 21:00:00.000
PL1007550   240587 3570   2017-09-09 22:00:00.000
```

And Here how my query looks like:

```
Item        Qty     cnt
211585      1200    1
211970      13936   33
270526      900     1
240468      42000   4
280102      25600   27
219074      9984    20
240519      33000   1
240519      10560   1
270053374   15840   4
223133      2400    10
```

As you can see in my query the item 240519 appears twice. I need only one row, with the group that conatins the stock units with the most recent GenerationDate

Comment: I'm not quite following what your data looks like.  Can you provide a bit more sample data and desired results?

Comment: Is there an `Id` or something on the table that indicates what the "most recent stock unit" might be?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Diego I've updated my answer based on the new information, but what I can't understand is what the `Count()` is being used for?

Comment: The Count()  is used to find how many stock unit has the same quantity, because i have to find the max number, for every item, and the quantity related.
So, once i found it, if there are multiple max count for the same item with the same value, i have to find the quanity (and the max-count) with the most recent stock unit in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.  There is an assumption that there is an `Id` on the table that indicates the order that the record was entered.  This is being used to determine what the most recent stock unit is:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *, 
            RN      = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Item Order By GenerationDate Desc),
            MaxQty  = Max(Qty) Over (Partition By Item)
    From    SI_UDC
    Where   Item Like '2%'
)
Select  Item, Qty
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
And     MaxQty = Qty
```

This query will pull the stock unit item whose max quantity is equal to the most recent entry's current quantity based on the `GenerationDate` column.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, i'm not practical with Row_Number and Partition, but i think it miss the Maximum count of the same quantity.